# Copy-paste full-path-file.ext string into command line directly from windows folder view

Tags: windows, powershell, command-line

Is there a way to copy-paste a **filename with full path** to the command line in Windows directly by right or left clicking the filename **IN FOLDER (BROWSING) VIEW**? Pasting a path is simple (by copying from top of the folder), but entering a full path/file.ext as an argument value requires typing or a separate select-filename's-text, F2, select all, and copy-paste?

For example copy this entire string directly to command line in one move from folder view (or whatever is called when the windows are open listing the many files)?:

```
C:\Users\aaa\Desktop\file.txt
```

I tried various combinations of right an left clicks, copy, paste, alt, shift, ctrl, does not work.

Comment: of course you can paste from clipboard anything. the Q if you can paste a filename with full path from folderview directly.

Comment: @bill-stewart it does NOT work. open any dir with files inside, select  the last file on the bottom, for example, and try to paste into the command line with one shot. does not work. need to select the path on top, copy-paste, then select the file separately F2, copy-paste again. its cumbersome.

Comment: Drag and drop the file into the command prompt or powershell session.

Comment: Shift+right click in explorer on any file or directory and select copy as path in the context menu. Here is a [link](https://www.google.com/url?sa=t&amp;amp;source=web&amp;amp;rct=j&amp;amp;url=https://www.pcworld.com/article/251406/windows_tips_copy_a_file_path_show_or_hide_extensions.amp.html&amp;amp;ved=0ahUKEwi8nt76j6bXAhUL4SYKHRfnAngQFggzMAI&amp;amp;usg=AOvVaw1y2PByG-XpNV_pe0ag1b6D&amp;amp;ampcf=1)

Answer (score 3):

**Method 1:**
Works by drag and drop the file into the command prompt. It does not work in powershell (5 1).

**Method 2:**
Shift+right click in explorer on any file or directory and select copy as path in the context menu. Works in CL and PS.